# How can I start a PHP foreach loop at a particular index, and still go through the entire loop?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array with the days of the week as the key (Mon, Tue, etc.). When going through the loop, I want to start on a particular day, then continue through the entire loop so I get all of the days. Any thoughts on how I can do this?

Comment: if you need to reset the iteration, start to some offset, you need some manual looping.. [check out this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13382232/1978142) this may shed some light

Comment: You might look into [ArrayIterator::seek](http://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayiterator.seek.php)

Comment: use a for loop instead of a foreach and you can then specify the iterator as  the starting point of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: missed that you need to search by key. The following should work:

```
$days = array('wed' => 2, 'thu' => 3, 'fri' => 4, 'sat' => 5, 'sun' => 6, 'mon' => 0, 'tue' => 1);

if ($off = array_search('mon', array_keys($days))) {
    $result = array_merge(array_slice($days, $off, null, true), array_slice($days, 0, $off, true));
    echo print_r($result, true);
}

/*
Array
(
    [mon] => 0
    [tue] => 1
    [wed] => 2
    [thu] => 3
    [fri] => 4
    [sat] => 5
    [sun] => 6
)
 */
```

Explanation: use [`array_keys`](http://php.net/array_keys) to find the numeric index of the key in the target array. Then use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array_merge) and [`array_splice`](http://php.net/array_splice) to cut the array into two parts, everything from the index to the end of the array and everything from the beginning to before the index.

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop:

```
//there are 7 days of the week, 0-6 in an array
$days = array('Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat');
$startIndex = 4; //the INDEX day we are starting at
$offset = 0;  

//loop through 7 times regardless
for($i=0; $i<7; $i++){
    $dayIndex = $startIndex+$offset;
    echo $days[$dayIndex];           //day we want
    if($dayIndex == 6){              //we want to start from the beginning 
        $offset = $startIndex * -1;  //multiply by -1 so $startIndex+$offset will eval to 0
    }else{
        $offset++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you simply want to iterate from particular index, try

```
$days = array('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun');
foreach (array_slice($days, 2) as $day)
    echo($day . "\n");
```

It will iterate from index 2 till last item. And it will work exactly the same with any keys.